# NSOutlineView's noteNumberOfRowsChanged isn't equivalent to reloadData

Tags: cocoa, datasource, nsoutlineview

I add another `Object` to my `NSOutlineView`'s `NSOutlineViewDataSource` and call `[myOutlineView noteNumberOfRowsChanged]`. If I read the documentation correctly this should get the OutlineView to realize I added one row and redraw itself properly. But instead nothing happens.

If I call `[myOutlineView reloadData]` it works, but according to the documentation `reloadData` has a much higher overhead than `noteNumberOfRowsChanged` (since it reloads all data ... duh)

I'm not using bindings, I supply `NSOutlineViewDataSource` myself.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `reloadData:` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/reloadData):

> If you just want to update the
>   scroller, use noteNumberOfRowsChanged;
>   if the height of a set of rows
>   changes, use
>   noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:.

<strike>To me that sounds like that `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` only ensures that the newly added object is visible within the view.</strike>

The discussion section of the `reloadData:` documentation also mentions a way to *update* a single row. But it seems that `reloadData:` is the only option if you add new objects.